# How to set image on UIImageview with array containing paths of document directory which have been fetched from SQLite Database?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

Can you please tell me how to set image on imageview with array containing paths of document directory which have been fetched from SQLite Database.

```
> - (IBAction)retBTN:(id)sender {
>     
>     sqlite3_stmt *statment;
>     const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
>     
>     if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_DB)==SQLITE_OK){
>         
>         NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT path FROM imagepath"];
>         const char *query_statment = [querySQL UTF8String];
>         
>         if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_DB, query_statment, -1, &statment, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
>             
>             self.arrname = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
>             
>             while(sqlite3_step(statment)==SQLITE_ROW){
>                 
>             [self.arrname addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment,0)]];
>                 NSLog(@"%@",self.arrname);
>                 
>             }
> 
> 
>         }
> 
>         sqlite3_finalize(statment);
>         sqlite3_close(_DB);
>     }
>     
>      }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you got successfull path?

Comment: yes i am getting the path successful

Comment: I dont have idea how to trim the path so that i can put it on Imageview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try it.
NSString *imagePath = [self.arrname lastObject];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
[imageView setImage:image];

and also tell me where the image is stored, I meant is it stored locally or is it stored it in Database?
```

Comment: yes it is stored locally on phone which is changing by date time stamp.

Comment: NSString * timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f.png",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];

Comment: are you storing this path in database and image locally in documents directory? then the above code works correctly. Try to debug it and print the path and go there check it whether the image exists or not.

Comment: Ok i am checking it now

Comment: If it works, please upvote my answer, It would helpful to some one.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
NSString *directory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", directory,self.imagename];
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pngFilePath];
```

Comment: This will not work becoz i am saving the path with time stamp

    NSString * timestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f.png",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *smallpath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsPath,timestamp];

Comment: add your path in comment

Comment: @Harjot Singh Panesar add path output

Comment: "/Users/harjotsingh/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B5AF2EE2-4417-4426-A2C8-17059AC62F6B/data/Containers/Data/Application/CE909E5B-4381-46D8-AFC0-5B9693B19960/Documents/1488801173379.348877.png"

Comment: this is your sqlite database image path?

Comment: Actually the path is coming from SQLite Database stored in a variable and yes database is also stored in same place.

Comment: @HarjotSinghPanesar compare my code path and your sqlite data path .post in comment.because code is right

Comment: i have tried dis code and i am getting the value in this (UIImage *) image1 = 0x00000000a7baadb1

I have tried dis code and i am getting the value this time but in memory address.
            NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", directory,[_arrname objectAtIndex:0]];

Comment: @HarjotSinghPanesar add this line than pass image1 data to your imageview UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pngFilePath];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137337/discussion-between-jigar-and-harjot-singh-panesar).

Comment: NSString *directory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", directory,[_arrname objectAtIndex:0]];
            UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pngFilePath];
            
            _imgRef.image = image1;
Still not working.

Comment: Thanks @Jigar. Ur code have not solved my problem but u have helped me a lot.